# Is TLS enough for client server encryption or if dealing with sensitive data, its better to add ur own encryption also. for example leverage AWS SSM?

Tags: node.js, react-native, encryption, aws-ssm

I have a Front End React Native application, and i am dealing with sensitive information. Asides their auth information, I tried encrypting, which i thought was a good idea to do. I'm encrypting using AWS with the keys stored on SSM, I also have to process payment transaction. These are all communicating with the server? Should i just rely on TLS to do the necessary encryption for the data in Transit?

As mentioned i am currently using AWS SSM to encrypt, although i fear for the security of the application.

Comment: Are you talking about encrypting data in the browser before sending it to your servers over HTTP?